# How to manage translations of help pages in debian packaging?

Tags: deb, packaging, locale, translation

I am trying to create debian package for an upstream source (which has not been debian packaged yet), and want to know if help pages translated in a new locale can be automatically configured in the .deb package.

To install the help pages, we need to copy the contents of `source/help/C/` into `/usr/share/help/C/packagename/`.
I can do that by adding the following line to `debian/install`

```
help/C/* /usr/share/help/C/packagename/
```

If any translations of the help pages are added, they will also need to be copied from `source/help/LANG/` into `/usr/share/help/LANG/packagename/` where `LANG` could be any locale.

How to achieve this dynamically (using wildcards or something like that), so that we won't have to manually edit `debian/install` when translations for a new locale are added?

Otherwise I would have to to manually add a line to `debian/install` every time translations for a new language are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to make an `override_dh_install:` entry in `debian/rules` to deal with it. I haven't the time to draft an example right now, but you may want to give that a thought.

*Edit:*

Ok, this is the method I had in mind in the form of a diff:

```
diff -ru recipe.orig/debian/install recipe/debian/install
--- recipe.orig/debian/install  2021-01-11 20:08:08.000000000 +0100
+++ recipe/debian/install   2021-01-13 09:29:50.645316616 +0100
@@ -2,4 +2,3 @@
 res/com.github.alexhuntley.Plots.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/
 res/com.github.alexhuntley.Plots-symbolic.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic/apps/
 res/com.github.alexhuntley.Plots.metainfo.xml /usr/share/metainfo/
-help/C/* /usr/share/help/C/plots/
\ No newline at end of file
diff -ru recipe.orig/debian/rules recipe/debian/rules
--- recipe.orig/debian/rules    2021-01-13 09:27:58.952883958 +0100
+++ recipe/debian/rules 2021-01-13 09:25:00.736193794 +0100
@@ -6,3 +6,15 @@
 
 %:
        dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem=pybuild
+
+override_dh_install:
+   dh_install
+   # install docs in available languages
+   cd help; \
+   for lang in `ls`; do \
+       cd $$lang; \
+       for doc in `ls`; do \
+           install -m 644 -D $$doc $(CURDIR)/debian/plots/usr/share/help/$$lang/plots/$$doc ; \
+       done; \
+       cd .. ; \
+   done
```

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this with `override_dh_install:`. If possible, when you get time, please provide a small example or point me to a suitable site/similar source package which does this job. I am not in a hurry.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: If you make a buildable version of the source available somehow, I can play with it and make a suggestion. Maybe put it in a PPA.

Comment: Here is the [source](https://github.com/alexhuntley/Plots), and here is the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~apandada1/+archive/ubuntu/plots). Note that so far no translations are available. I was just wondering if there is any way to manage all the translations simultaneously, once they are available in future. Thanks

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: Please see edited answer.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: When working with another package, I realized that my answer is hackish. If you run `man dh_installdocs` you see what's probably the most proper way to handle it.

Comment: I will look at it, thanks.